# Data Error (Cyclic Redundancy Check) during hard drive format?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, chkdsk

I received a new HDD from my uncle, RAW file system. Tried `CHKDSK`, but it didn't work because of the RAW file system.

[image]

---

### Update

I ran SpinRite 6 overnight and it got nowhere. Stayed at 0% for the whole 10 hours. SpinRite also gave me a notification that this drive is most probably toast. I think I am going to throw this drive away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can't successfully format the drive, the likelihood of it being a bad (failed) HDD is pretty high.

To be totally sure, I'd try formatting it on another PC -- either by hooking it up via SATA directly or using a USB enclosure.

Answer (score 2):

Most hard drive manufacturers offer a drive diagnostic program for download, which can help verify whether it is a defective drive.

I would also try swapping out the cable (especially if it's parallel ATA), and try a different controller/port/PC, just to double-check that the drive is at fault.

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to be formatting your SD card or HDD via a USB extension cable or a USB hub, this error can present itself: be sure the device you are formatting is plugged directly into the computer when formatting.